# Traversing dictionary of list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, traversal

I am new to python and having trouble traversing this type of structure. Any help would be appreciated.

I would like to print "name" field from each book type:

```
[
 {   'books': [   {   u'published': 1957,
                     u'name': u'The Cat In The Hat'},
                 {   u'published': 1947,
                     u'name': u'Goodnight Moon'},
                 {   u'published': 1964,
                     u'name': u'The Giving Tree'}],
   'type': u'Kids'
}
{   'books': [   {   u'published': 1954,
                     u'name': u'The Lord Of The Rings'},
                 {   u'published': 2008,
                     u'name': u'The Hunger Games'}],
   'type': u'Adventure'
 }
]
```

Here is the code I have that is not working:

```
for books in d:
   book = books['book']
   for name in files.iteritems():
       print name
```

Comment: `d` is a string, is that just a typo here?

Comment: You appear to have a **string**, not a dictionary. The string contains what appear to be *two* main dictionaries.

Comment: What about it isn't working? What happens and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: I don't mean 'd' to be a string but that is the structure.  Its not printing the book name.

Comment: Well if that's the structure, then it *is* a string, and it's not printing the book name because you're operating on a string as if it's a dictionary..

Comment: Re update: Lists are comma separated, but your outer list is not. Typo? You still haven't elaborated on "not working".

Answer (score 0):

Your first issue is that `d` is a string - lose those quotes around the `{ }` braces.

Then `for books in d` gives you each key in the dictionary as a variable `books`. Those keys are `books` and `type`.

You then have another syntax error - the dictionary ends (`}`), and you then open 'another', without declaring it as a new variable.

I expect you wanted the dictionary something more like:

```
books = {
    'Kids': [
        {'published': 1957, 'name': u'The Cat in the hat'},
        {'published': 1964, 'name': u'The Giving Tree'},
        {'published': 1947, 'name': u'Goodnight Moon'}
    ],
    'Adventure': []
}
```

And then you can do something like:

```
for bookType in books:
    for book in books[bookType]:
        print book['name']
```

Comment: I'm sorry about the confusion but that is the structure that is populated that I'm working with.